# how to pass variable or object to aiogram dp.message_handler decorated function?

Tags: python, chatbot

I am trying to use aiogram building a chatbot, but find no example provided by the package is helpful. The problem is I can't find a way to pass my own object or variables from main to my chat function decorated by `'dp.message_handler()'`. I need passing objects and variable which are text generator to chat function, so bot can chat instead of just echoing.  I used their echo example as starting point, I can get user message at `'message.text'` no problem...my code is like:

```
    @dp.message_handler()
    async def chat(message: types.Message, myobj, myvar):
        "using myobj and myvar to generate text as reply"
        await message.answer(reply)
        return message.text
     
    async def main():
        while Ture:
            said = await partial(chat, myobj=qna_model, myvar=text)
            if said == "bye": break
        dp.stop_polling()
        await dp.wait_closed()
        await bot.session.close()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

But I got error: `TypeError: chat() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'myobj' and 'myvar'.`
I even tried `'async def chat(message: types.Message, **kwargs)'` and call it from `main()` without partial wraper, also no luck... I searched and can't find example about how to use aiogram to build a chatbot, may be I am in a wrong way of using aiogram... Has anyone used aiogram building chatbot successfully?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wanna pass a function to your handler just import it and use it directly.
If you wanna apply it for some handlers, you should use a middleware.

### Direct usage

```py
def generate_text():
    return "generated text"

async def handler(message: Message):
    text = generate_text()
    await message.answer(text)
```

### Middleware usage

Create a middleware

```py
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import Message

class YourMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    async def on_pre_process_message(self, message: Message, data: dict):
        # `text` is a name of var passed to handler
        data["text"] = generate_text()
```

Register it via Dispatcher (on_startup)

```py
dp.middleware.setup(YourMiddleware())
```

Get `text` data inside the handler

```py
from aiogram.types import Message

async def handler(message: Message, text: str):
    await message.answer(text)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.   I can't place text_generator in a separate function which is different namespace, as the generator model is stored in local drive, every time call generator function will have to reload the model. In fact, my first trial was to load the model inside chat function, but bot response is too slow to be acceptable until  I move the while loop into chat function...that obviously is not the solution. .

Comment: In this case, I am not sure if Middlewere can solve the problem or not.  I don't know how Middlewere works, Would you please provide a completed code example for this case?  I don't see YourMiddlewere class created any instance and which code to call its function on_pre_process_message.

Comment: `on_pre_process_message` is called by `Dispatcher` before processing every message

Answer (score -1):

aiogram actually has a way to pass data into message handler decorated function which is equivalent to the way of direct external function call given by Oleg, and easier than Middleware.

```
    async def myfunc(message: types.Message):
        myrparm = dict()
        myrparm["model"] = mymodel
        myrparm["reply"] = generator(message.text)
        return myparm

    @dp.message_handler(myfunc)
    async def chat(message: types.Message, model, reply):
         "do some thing with model or reply to get final_reply "
        await message.answer(final_reply)
```

condition is myfunc must return a dictionary.
In this way, I can place generator in either myfunc or chat no difference. To address long time of loading generator model problem, I setup a user command something like "/load model" and make the generator stay as global variable(or may use Redis), thus user only suffer slow response when issue the load command while chatting response is acceptable.